# error C2664 cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'TCHAR *'

Tags: c++, winapi

Прекрасно компилируется в codeblocks а в Visual studio выдает

error C2664 cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'TCHAR *'
message : Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
message : see declaration of 'MessageBoxPrintf'

В чем причина?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int CDECL MessageBoxPrintf(TCHAR* szCaption, TCHAR* szFormat, ...)
{
    TCHAR szBuffer[1024];
    va_list pArgList;
    // The va_start macro (defined in STDARG.H) is usually equivalent to:
    // pArgList = (char *) &szFormat + sizeof (szFormat) ;
    va_start(pArgList, szFormat);
    // The last argument to wvsprintf points to the arguments
    wprintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer) / sizeof(TCHAR),
                szFormat, pArgList);
    // The va_end macro just zeroes out pArgList for no good reason
    va_end(pArgList);
    return MessageBox(NULL, szBuffer, szCaption, 0);
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    int cxScreen, cyScreen;
    cxScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    cyScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    MessageBoxPrintf(TEXT("ScrnSize"),
                     TEXT("The screen is %i pixels wide by %i pixels high."),
                     cxScreen, cyScreen);
    return 0;
}
```

пример и книжки Charles Petzold Programming Windows 5th Ed

Comment: TCHAR не const?

Comment: В примере было так, но с const TCHAR* заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В языке С++ строковые литералы не разрешается неявно преобразовывать к указателям на не-константу, о чем вам и говорит компилятор. Функция `MessageBoxPrintf` должна быть объявлена с параметрами типа `const TCHAR *`, а не `TCHAR *`.

А книжка ваша была написана во времена динозавров, то есть во времена первого стандарта С++98, в котором такое неявно преобразование разрешалось для совместимости с C.

То, что у вас это "прекрасно компилируется в codeblocks" возможно означает что ваш codeblocks работает в старинном режиме C++98. Есть также вероятность, что в codeblocks вы компилировали этот код в режиме С.

---

Также, здесь написана белиберда

```
wprintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        szFormat, pArgList);
```

Подозреваю, что имелся в виду `vswprintf`? В книге использован именно `wprintf`?

Также, использование `va_list` требует `<stdarg.h>`, а использование `vswprintf` требует `<wchar.h>`.

Comment: Спасибо, c _vsntprintg и const TCHAR* все работает.
/

Только где взять современную книгу с рабочими примерами

Comment: @Gera: `_vsntprintf`. Вы, видимо, компилируетесь в режиме узких символов. То есть фактически вам нужна `vsnprintf`, или, если уж единообразно писать "самотрансформирующийся" код в терминах `TCHAR`, то `_vsntprintf`.